# Friendly name for special $end token in Bison

Tags: bison

With older versions of Bison, verbose error messages sometimes look like this:

```
syntax error, unexpected [, expecting $end
```

Is there a way to give `$end` a more user-friendly name? In newer versions this is "end of file". Can I get this in older versions as well?

For user-defined tokens I can specify a name as `%token NUM "number"`, but how can I do this for `$end`?

Comment: You can write your own `yyerror` function that filters the error message it gets from bison, replacing `$end` with `end of file`

Comment: @ChrisDodd That's possible, but both ugly and complicated ... So the name for `$end` cannot be directly overriden, like with other tokens?

Comment: Doesn't `%token END 0 "friendly name"` work? (Not in front of a machine right now, sorry.)

Comment: @rici Yes, it works. How much of a hack is this, i.e. assuming that the value is zero? These two also work, and perhaps they are more robust? `%token YYEOF "foofoofoo"` or `%token END YYEOF "foofoofoo"`. However, they produce the warning: "(empty location): warning: symbol YYEOF given more than one literal string [-Wother]"

Comment: In fact, `%token YYEOF "foofoofoo"` does not work with some older Bison versions, such as the ancient version that ships with macOS. It leads to `error: 'YYEOF' macro redefined`.  Your suggestion of using `%token END 0 "friendly name"` does work.

Comment: @rici If you post it, I'll accept. I also got a response on the Bison mailing list in the meantime. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bison/2022-05/msg00001.html

Comment: It's here in the Bison manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Token-I18n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify an alias for the end-of-input token, you can use:

```
%token END 0 "friendly name"
```

That declares that the token id `END` has code 0, and gives a friendly name to that code.

You could use any otherwise unused symbol instead of `END`, such as `ZERO` or `FRED`. Whatever symbol you use will be `#define`d to 0, or declared as an `enum` label with value 0 (depending on bison version), but as long as you don't use the symbol, that fact is not very interesting.

You cannot use `YYEOF` or `EOF`, because both of those are reserved (and have other definitions). The first is reserved by Bison itself, as are all symbols starting `yy` or `YY`, and the second is reserved by C. If you attempt to redefine a reserved name (whether manually or with a code generator) the result is Undefined Behaviour, whether or not you are presented with a diagnostic and whether or not it appears to work in some context.

The syntax of the `%token` declaration is a series of triples consisting of a symbol, an optional literal integer, and an optional quoted string. What you want to do as associate an alias (the quoted string) with a token code (the integer), but the syntax doesn't let you do that without specifying some symbol. Explicit token codes are very rarely useful, so that limitation is not particularly onerous. The end-of-input code 0 is probably the only useful explicit code.

Note that `%token END YYEOF "foo"` (taken from one of the comments) declares *two* tokens, both with codes selected by Bison. (And one of the symbol names is reserved, which leads to Undefined Behaviour, as noted above.) So that's certainly not what you want. If you're going to supply an alias for code 0, you must have a token declaration with the literal integer 0.

It is documented that 0 is the token code for end of input in the section describing the interaction with the lexer. 0 is how the lexer indicates end of input. That's a fixed aspect of the C interface, and it's safe to assume it will continue to work for the indefinite future. `yylex` can also return a negative number with the same effect, but that's translated into token code 0. The use of `%token END 0 "..."` to declare an alias for end of input appears in the example code in the manual, and in any number of real-life parsers (and SO answers).